# DDD strategic design vs global dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, domain-driven-design

Do global dictionaries like countries (codes/names) or currencies (code/names) belong to certain domain in DDD or may be shared as common lib/seperate module of application layer?

From one side DDD requires to keep all business stuff in given domain.
From the other side countries/currencies are all the same in each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter 15 (Distillation) of Evans - Domain Driven Design is probably the reference you want.

Evans uses *Generic Subdomain* for those areas that are essential to the functioning of the system but are not the specialties that are your primary focus.

Currencies, Time Zones, Location Codes...

Evans's guidance is:

> Identify cohesive subdomains that are not the motivation for your project.  Factor out generic models of these subdomains and place them in separate MODULES.  Leave no trace of your specialties in them.
>
> ....consider off-the-shelf solutions or published models for these GENERIC SUBDOMAINS.

Answer (score 1):

It depends (tm) on the domain. If you have a 'general' application and your interest in a country, currency or money is just a value, then they can be part of a library. For example the JVM has a `Currency` class (and will have soon a `Money` class too), and there are libraries for many other types (e.g. telephone numbers).

**But** if you are designing a different system, for example an application that explores the history of countries, a `Country` class in that domain will have a lot more information rather than just the 3 letter ISO code. And some long gone countries won't have an ISO code either!

From this you can see that the statement *countries/currencies are all the same in each of them* is actually not valid.